# Ember 2.0 router does not load model data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have in my router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('portfolio', function() {
    this.route('company', { path:'/company/:id' });
  });
}
```

And in my routes/portfolio/company.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
    var companyId = params.id;
    return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
            company: Ember.$.ajax({ url: '/api/company/'+companyId, dataType: "json", type: 'GET' })
        }).then(function(message) {
            return message;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log( error );
        });
    }
});
```

My route and template is loading fine, when I navigate to `app/portfolio/company/1`, but for some reason when I navigate to that route, Ember wont load the model (no error, but the {{model}} variable does not get populated in template). Only when I refresh the page, Ember loads the model?! I am a bit confused now...

Edit: added missing param and added better description

Comment: " when I navigate to that route, Ember wont load the model" - what does that mean? Is there some error in console, blank page or what?

Comment: I added better description, but basically model function does not get called and {{model}} variable in template does not get populated

Comment: Model function won't get called if you are passing a model to your `link-to` helper, pass the `model.id` instead.

Comment: Thanks Kitler! Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your template or in controller you are using model like so 
`model.company` replace it with `model`, and remove extraneous `RSVP.hash`
because `Ember.$.ajax` already returns promise which model hooks can handle
so in ES6 (ember-cli supports it) your model hook should look like this

```
model({ id }) {
  return Ember.$.ajax('/api/company/' + id);
}
```

with above things everything should work, what was happening I think you were passing just `model` to `{{link-to}}` while your controller or template expecting `model.company` so was breaking things

Comment: The issue was that I was passing whole model in the {{link-to}} helper. When I passed model.id instead it started working fine. Thanks though for the answer Bek.

Comment: @MaksimLuzik you can pass `model` to `link-to`  as well it is possible to